# Multiple object in array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, java.util.scanner

I want to create objects using the result from `Scanner` and add them to an array.

However, each time I ask for user input for the second time, it just overwrites the first object.

How can I add multiple objects to the array?

Here's my code:

```
public void ajoutadd() {
    int i=0;
    boolean boucle=true;
    while(i!=2){
        Scanner thegame = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("name: \n");
        String jname = lejeu.nextLine();
        System.out.print(jname);
        Scanner qty = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("qty \n");
        int jqty = qty.nextInt();
        Scanner cat = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("cat: \n");
        String categ = cat.nextLine();
        Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("price: \n");
        int jprice = price.nextInt();
        Game agame = new Game(jname,jqty,categ,jprice);
        System.out.print(unjeu.Nom);

        // creating the array to contain the game(s)
        ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>(); 

        thegame.add(new Game(jname,jqty,categ,jprice));

        // actually only display 1 object that is overwritten
        // each time after the loop
        System.out.println(thegame);

        i=i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is not actually overwriting the first value. It is just creating a `new ArrayList` every time you loop through.

You should create one ArrayList and continously add to it.

ex.

```
ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
while(...) {
   ...
   games.add(...);
   ...
}
```

Couple notes:

- You do not have to create a `new Scanner` for every `scan` you can just use the same one (Also initialize it outside the loop like the array list).
- `i=i++` could just be `i++`, `i++` increments the variable i, it is different than `i + 1`. It is equivalent to `i = i + 1`.
- It is good practice to use the `List` interface for the `ArrayList` variable so that your code will work the same regardless of which `List` implementation you use.

Comment: thanks a lot.Good advice and answer.I created only one scanner like you said,however theres something wrong at the cat and price input,when the compiler reach these,it prints cat: and price: and its like if the price: was going over cat: without letting time to input the cat String? I dont know if you understand what i mean.Like I cant input cat,it immediatly jump to price?

Answer (score 1):

Move initialization of list outside the loop. Currently, you are creating list object everytime in loop. Hence losing the reference to existing one.

```
public  ArrayList<Game> ajoutadd() {
    int i=0;
    boolean boucle=true;
     ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>(); 
    while(i!=2){
    Scanner thegame = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("name: \n");
    String jname = lejeu.nextLine();
    System.out.print(jname);
    Scanner qty = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("qty \n");
    int jqty = qty.nextInt();
    Scanner cat = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("cat: \n");
    String categ = cat.nextLine();
    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("price: \n");
    int jprice = price.nextInt();
    Game agame = new Game(jname,jqty,categ,jprice);
    System.out.print(unjeu.Nom);
   //creating the array to contain the game(s)
    thegame.add(new Game(jname,jqty,categ,jprice));
   each time after the loop


    i++;

    }
  System.out.println(thegame); 
  return  thegame;


}
```

Comment: And how do I return the arraylist to be able to use it in other class?

Comment: changed the return type to Arraylist and returned the list. Now you get this value in calling method. Kindly accept the answer or upvote if it works for you.

Comment: I did what you told me too,however when I try to call it in other methods, like public void disp(){ System.out.print(thegame);} the game doesnt get recognized...?

Comment: While calling from other method save the value in other variable and print them. ArrayList<Game> game = ajoutadd(); System.out.println(game);. thegame has method level scope so will not be recognized outside method but you can get returned value in variables

Comment: This is because this  variable in scope of method , but we added return statement so that we get value in calling method. disp(){ ArrayList<Game>  game = ajoutadd() ; System.out.println(game); } .

Comment: this doesnt work; im getting a stack overflow error.ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>(); its already in the thegame variable but still not accessible from outside the method

Answer (score 1):

Create one `Scanner` outside the loop and one `List` instance (and I suggest you use the interface). Like,

```
public void ajoutadd() {
    int i = 0;
    boolean boucle = true;
    Scanner thegame = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<>();
    while (i != 2) {
        System.out.print("name: \n");
        String jname = thegame.nextLine();
        System.out.print(jname);
        System.out.print("qty \n");
        int jqty = thegame.nextInt();
        System.out.print("cat: \n");
        String categ = thegame.nextLine();
        System.out.print("price: \n");
        int jprice = thegame.nextInt();
        Game agame = new Game(jname, jqty, categ, jprice);
        System.out.print(unjeu.Nom);
        thegame.add(new Game(jname, jqty, categ, jprice));
        System.out.println(thegame);
        i++; // <-- not i = i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do I return the arraylist to be able to use it in other class?

Comment: Change `public void ajoutadd() {` to `public List<Game> ajoutadd() {` and add a `return thegame;` after your `while` loop. Also, you should probably ask a new question (and do some research) on your own.